# How do you make hair with different colors on the same strand?

Tags: particles, hair

I want to make a skunk's tail but that would require the strands to be half white and the other black. How would I set up the hair particles to do this?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14673/particle-hair-material-with-random-streaks-for-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35403/highlights-with-hair/35433#35433

Comment: @cegaton Not hair with different colors each single hair has different colors. Like the root is one color and the tip another.

Comment: You can underly a texture on the emitter. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-hair-particles-acquire-color-from-emitters-uv-mapped-image

Answer (score 3):

Using the hair-info node's 'Intercept' output and a colorRamp node, you can control the color of a particle hair strand from root to tip.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is this Viewer node and where do I get it?

Comment: @EricHuelin - viewer in material nodes comes from the node wrangler addon.  Ctrl-Shift-Click on a non-bsdf node to create it. It is simply an emission node re-named to viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The hair emits from the tail stem in this example. The nodes set up uses the color ramp for each hair, the root is on the left side of the ramp. If you cut the hair or make it longer the ramp will scale for each strand.

[image]